# Cannot call class as a function error in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am making a ListView in React Native and getting **"Cannot call class as a function"** error. I also tried adding "new" keyword before class but still the error was not solved. Following is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, AppRegistry, ListView, Text} from 'react-native';

    class listview extends Component{

    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    var ds = ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged : (r1,r2) => r1!==r2});
    this.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['1','2','3','4'])
    }
    }

    _renderRow(rowData){
      return <Text>{rowData}</Text>;
      }

    render(){
    return(
    <ListView
    dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow = {this._renderRow.bind(this)}
    />
    );
    }
    }
    AppRegistry.registerComponent('listview', () => listview );
```

You can see the error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14Y0m.png). How do I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged : (r1,r2) => r1!==r2});
  //-------^^^ you forgot to place `new` keyword here.
  this.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['1','2','3','4'])
  }
}
```